# Xcode Localization Files Are Copied Incorrectly

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, plist

I'm adding Localization for a `.plist` file in my project, so that on my project folder I have this file both in the `es.proj` and `en.proj`. However when I try to compile and run the app it will use a third file (I tried to modify the ones that I have without any change in the app).

I've taken a look at `/Users/Developer/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/appid/AppName.app` and actually there are 3 `Questions.plist`files, one in the base directory and two, as expected in the `.proj` ones. How can I find out from where it comes from?

Comment: Just stating the obvious to double check, 1) Are you sure that there are 2 plist files in Xcode in the proper locations and 2) Have you done a clean build?

Comment: @lucianomarisi I have `Questions.plist` in `AppName.app`, `AppName.app/es.proj` and `AppName.app/en.proj` in the simulator and in `MyApp/en.proj` and `MyApp/es.proj` in my project folder. I've already tried to do a Clean and Run without any result.

Comment: What about in copy bundle resources in build phases? Somehow you are copying an extra file onto the root directory. To be honest if all else fails, just remove all files and add them again, it'll probably take you 5min to do that.

Comment: @lucianomarisi ok, I've tried to remove both files and do a Clean and Run, of course the file is still here and the application works fine. The file is neither in the Project Navigator and in the Copy Bundle Resources of the Build Phases tab.

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean you removed all the Questions.plist files but one of them is still there??

Comment: @lucianomarisi it's still in the application bundle inside the simulator.

Comment: Does Questions.plist appear if you search for it in the project navigator?

Answer (score 0):

Product → Clean

Then reset the Simulator (iOS Simulator → Reset Content and Settings…).

Then try running the app again.